# Sublime Text syntax: Python 3.6 f-strings

Tags: python, syntax, sublimetext3, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to modify the default `Python.sublime_syntax` file to handle Python’s f-string literals properly. My goal is to have expressions in interpolated strings recognised as such:

```
f"hello {person.name if person else 'there'}"
         -----------source.python----------
------string.quoted.double.block.python------
```

Within f-strings, ranges of text between a single `{` and another `}` (but terminating before format specifiers such as `!r}`, `:<5}`, etc—see [PEP 498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#specification)) should be recognised as expressions. As far as I know, that might look a little like this:

```
...
string:
 - match: "(?<=[^\{]\{)[^\{].*)(?=(!(s|r|a))?(:.*)?\})" # I'll need a better regex
   push: expressions
```

However, upon inspecting the build-in `Python.sublime_syntax` file, the string contexts especially are to unwieldy to even approach (~480 lines?) and I have no idea how to begin. Thanks heaps for any info.

Comment: Using a regex debugger such as https://regex101.com/ might help parsing the very log regex pattern

Comment: This is now fixed in `Build 3127`

Answer (score 2):

There was an update to syntax highlighting in BUILD 3127 (Which includes: Significant improvements to Python syntax highlighting).

However, a couple users have stated that in BUILD 3176 syntax highlighting still is not set to correctly highlight Python expressions that are located within f strings. According to @Jollywatt, it is set to source.python `f"string.quoted.double.block {constant.other.placeholder}"` rather than `f"string.quoted.double.block {source.python}"`

It looks like Sublime uses this tool, [PackageDev](https://github.com/SublimeText/PackageDev), "to ease the creation of snippets, syntax definitions, etc. for Sublime Text."

Comment: It doesn’t actually seem like this is ‘fixed’. In Build 3176, Python is still interpreted like `source.python f"string.quoted.double.block {constant.other.placeholder}"`, not `source.python f"string.quoted.double.block {source.python}"`. I wonder if the latter shouldn’t be the desired behaviour after all…

Comment: @Jollywatt that may be a better answer than mine. I switched my answer to a community wiki if you'd like to add that info.

Comment: I'm also using Build 3176 and unlike in Atom Editor, I don't see any the ordinary Python syntax highlighting within f-strings.